# Конкатенация в Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Есть `list<string>` ColumnsList и запрос к нему

```
var query = string.Join(", ", ColumnsList.Where(i => ColumnsList.Contains(i)));
```

Результат : Value1, Value2, ....

Мне нужно в єтом LINQ запросе сделать конкатенацию значений, что бы в результате было бы что то в виде

PlusValue1, PlusValue2, ...

Comment: используй [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `ColumnsList.Where(i => ColumnsList.Contains(i))` - всегда возвращает все строки из ColumnsList

Comment: Ну так мне и нужно что бы все строки возвращало, но я еще хочу добавить к этим строкам другую строку "Plus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отображения одной коллекции на другую, следует использовать метод [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

В данном случае вместо `where` нужно сделать так:

```
var query = string.Join(", ", ColumnsList.Select(s => "Plus"+s));
```

Либо с новым синтаксисом

```
var query = string.Join(", ", ColumnsList.Select(s => $"Plus{s}"));
```